# What's the correct way to listen for a Google+ Hangout state change?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

The Hangout API at https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing includes an example to set a callback function when the hangout state has changed, like this:

```
gapi.hangout.onStateChanged.add(onStateChange);
```

When run, this results in an error similar to "**gapi.hangout.onStateChanged is undefined**". A quick check in Firebug shows that the `onStateChanged` method belongs to `gapi.hangout.data` **not** `gapi.hangout`.

What is the correct way to add a callback function when the state has changed?

Comment: I heard the Hangouts API team reads SO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method that you're looking for is indeed a member of [gapi.hangout.data](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/reference#gapi.hangout.data). The writing article you mention seems to be out of date. I fix it :)

To do something when state changes just attach a callback:

```
gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged.add(function() {
  console.log(gapi.hangout.data.getState());
});
```

You can find working examples of the code in action on the [sample apps](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps) page.

Comment: Tip: the onStateChange events callback returns the StateChangedEvent as parameter, so its not needed for a extra call to the getState() function.